# AAR has a placeholder when confused by ProGuard, resulting in failure

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

An Android library project, environment:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
Gradle 4.9
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
        <activity
        android:name="${applicationId}.PayloadActivity" />
```

When I use ProGuard to obfuscate code:

```
Caused by: proguard.ParseException: Expecting class member name before '}' in line 2 of file 'Y:\project\build\intermediates\proguard-rules\release\aapt_rules.txt'
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.checkJavaIdentifier(ConfigurationParser.java:1486)
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.checkJavaIdentifier(ConfigurationParser.java:1472)
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseMemberSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:1049)
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:876)
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:659)
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:588)
    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:165)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.applyConfigurationFile(BaseProguardAction.java:145)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:254)
    ... 5 more
```

build\intermediates\proguard-rules\release\aapt_rules.txt:

```
# Generated by the gradle plugin
-keep class ${applicationId}.PayloadActivity { <init>(...); }
```

Confusion failed because there was no placeholder assignment when compiling into AAR. Although confusion can be delayed until it is compiled into APK. However, because of this part of the content, I do not want to be seen by APK users with such simple decompilation. Is it possible to get confused when compiling AAR?

Comment: there should be no `<activity
        android:name="${applicationId}.PayloadActivity" />` for aar project.

Comment: Do you have any idea to reslove this problem ?

Comment: @peerless2012 So far, I have no solution

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
<activity android:name="${applicationId}.PayloadActivity" />
```

from your `manifest.xml` file.